# How to print words containing unicode?

Tags: java

I need to print Swedish words that contain unicode using Java
how can I do it?

for example

Text with Unicode:- \u228sk\u228da

Output: åskåda

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Java has unicode support by default. Just make sure you are using the correct encoding when reading data. (UTF-8 for example)

Comment: actually I was trying to write an algorithm and did write several algorithms  for this that didn't work but from @FabiánHerediaMontiel answer I got to know it is much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the following would work:

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println("åskåda"); 
    System.out.println("\u00e5sk\u00e5da");
  } 
}
```

Note that you need to use the hex values and must take care of specifying the encoding when reading data (from disk or network)

Comment: Thanks!this really works,do you know how I can return what is printed because I need to return it as a String

Comment: Just return the strings then

Comment: Hey thanks!Can you please tell me under what section of Java can I study these?

Comment: can you please tell me how I can return the result  as a String?Beacuse my method expects it a return type String not void